# Changing the way files are found and linked in Qt Creator

Tags: macos, qt-creator, static-linking, symbols

I have an application I am creating in Qt Creator and I am linking to files in a big framework  on an svn, and for this I have a local copy of that svn. The problem I am having is that for example a header file on the svn has:

## include "files/source/db/extract.h"

and this in  my local computer would be: #include "home/user/sv/files/source/db/extract.h"

Therefore I get the error "extract.h no such file".

I am able to include all the files changing the .pro file in Qt Creator doing INCLUDEPATH =

But all these files are read only and I cant change any of these files to point to where I have a local copy of other sources in the library.

Is there a way in Qt Creator where I can do something like:

/files/source/db = /home/user/sv/files/source/db so that everytime a file is included this way it can find the copy I have locally ?

I appreciate any help.

thank you.

Comment: You wrote "I am able to include all the files changing the .pro file in Qt Creator doing INCLUDEPATH". That's indeed the way to do it, so what's not working?

Comment: That the files I included with INCLUDEPATH refer to other files(the read only ones), and these "other" files, have includes like: #include "files/source/db/extract.h" which in my computer is in a slightly different path like explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Use INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/your/location /path/to/global/location, and the files in your/location will be picked up if they exist, befor global/location is examined.